# Лишние пробелы C++ string

Tags: c++, строки

Есть задачка из eolymp.

*Лишние пропуски
Дана строка. Напишите приложение, которое удалит из этой строки все лишние пробелы. Пробел будем считать лишним, если:
он находится в начале строчки, до первого слова;
он находится в конце строчки, после последнего слова;
несколько пробелов расположены между двумя словами (проще говоря, если слова разделены более чем одним пробелом, тогда все пробелы, кроме одного - лишние).

Технические условия
входные данные
Дана строка S (0 ≤ | S | ≤ 255). Строка содержит только латинские буквы и пробелы.
Пример входящих данных
Alexandr Sergeevich Pushkin
Пример исходных данных
Alexandr Sergeevich Pushkin*

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ukrainian");
    std::string str;
    std::cout << "Введiть рядок: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, str);

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ' && str[i + 1] == ' ') {
            str.erase(i, 1);
            i = i - 1;
        }
    }

    if (str[0] == ' ') {
        str.erase(0, 1);
    }

    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод в консоли работает как надо,ну по крайней мере то,что я проверял.Но вот eolymp засчитывает эту задачу на 0%. В чем может быть проблема этого кода?

Comment: обычно, в олимпиадных задачах не нужно ничего лишнего выводить - уберите строку `std::cout << "Введiть рядок: ";`

Comment: @KoVadim Тут появилась еще одна проблема,когда дойдет цикл до последнего пробела условие str[i + 1] выдает выход за границы массива,Как это можно решить

Comment: добавить ещё один кусочек в условие? Где то так `&& i+1 < str.size()`. Но вот `i=i-1` в цикле мне не очень нравиться, хотя работать будет.

Comment: Может есть вариант получше,потому что преподаватель сказал что оно работает,но замечание некорректное поведение с циклом for

Comment: Действительно без строки  std::cout << "Введiть рядок: "; eolymp засчитывает на 100% задачу,но вот мне кажется что это не совсем хороший код

Comment: Вы не проверили последний пробел.

Comment: код может и не очень хорош, но на олимпиадах важен факт быстрой сдачи и прохождения тестов. А в продашн коде - другие правила